# Problem deploying React-app to Heroku with proper styling

Tags: reactjs, heroku, sass

I created a MERN stack app. Then, deployed it to Heroku. It deployed fine, but I noticed some of my stylings were off. They look different than they did in Chrome developer tools. Does anybody know why this could be?

I used bootstrap and Sass to style the app.

[textarea after deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE9xY.png)

[textarea in development](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deTE7.png)

Comment: Please include some details. How are you including or importing or linking the styles?

Comment: @cbr I have an App.scss file that I imported to my App,js file.  Then I have multiple components in folders with their own scss files imported to them.

Comment: Most of the styling is there. it's just a few things that are off.

Comment: What kind of things are off? Is there any pattern to what's missing? Anything in common? Are there any 404s in the Network tab of your browser's developer tools? Are there any other stylesheets that you use, e.g. static CSS files?

Comment: Could you perhaps show a screenshot of what's different? Could you inspect the elements with your browser's developer tools to see which styles are missing?

Comment: Ok I added some pics to the post. All the problems are with textareas extending past their div, and some img's being distorted